# ESP32 dev board powering up issues

Tags: arduino-esp32

If I power my esp32-wroom dev board to my computer usb it works fine but if i connect it to an external 3.3v 2A powersupply it does not work. Although I see the logo pop up on the connected oled display so it must be booting but it does not do anything else that I had programmed it to do .
2A should have been enough for these board or not?

basically i am looking for an external 3.3v usb power adapter for my dev board.

Comment: off topic here, barely on topic on electronics.   However .2A != 2A.  the only way to find out is to get some tools on it: a 'scope on the power leads close to the esp will probably tell you what's happening, or watch the serial output.  But this isn't a programming problem.  As a wild guess I blame your psu: it might drop under load, or be noisy (esps are quite picky).